# Redirecting subprocess output to FIFO not working

Tags: c++, ipc, fifo

I'm forking a process and running mysqldump with execl. I want to redirect the output of mysqldump to FIFO I created. But opening of fifo is failing and so dup2().

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    char *fifoname="/home/maverick/myfifo";
    mkfifo(fifoname,0666);

    int forkret=fork();
    if(forkret==0){
        setuid(getpwnam("mysql")->pw_uid);
        cout<<"In child....Running as :"<<(int)getuid()<<endl;
        sleep(2);
        int fdw=open(fifoname,O_WRONLY);

         if ((dup2(fdw, STDOUT_FILENO)) != STDOUT_FILENO)
             cout<<"Error redirecting output of mysqldump ";
         if (dup2(fdw, STDERR_FILENO) != STDERR_FILENO)
             cout<<"Error redirecting error stream of mysqldump";
        execl("mysqldump","-u","root","-proot","--all-databases");
       }
    else{
        char buf[20];

     int fdr=open(fifoname,O_RDONLY);
     while(read(fdr,(char*)buf,sizeof(buf))!=0){
         cout<<buf;
     }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The open () call is failing..I can't understand what is wrong here..

Comment: You're not checking the result of `mkfifo` (or most of the other function calls for that matter). Did that succeed? What is the value of `errno` after `open` fails?

Comment: I can see the fifo with ls command...open is failing with -1

Comment: And what is the value of `errno` after it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the fifo allowing access only to the user and group that owns it, and then using `setuid` to change user. Presumably, the new user does not have permission to access the file.

You need to open the file *before* calling `setuid`.

Answer (score 0):

I use two different files instead of dup2. In the first file I open for writing in the parent and reading in the child. The second I open to the writing in the son and reading in the father.

In this question I show a little of how I do

[FIFO - Restore communication in C ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676486/fifo-restore-communication-in-c)