# FIFO - Restore communication in C ++

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, named-pipes, fifo

I have a main program written in C ++. It triggers child programs using vfork () and execl (). Communication between them works perfectly using FIFO (the parent writes and the child reads).

In the main program the sequence for establishing communication is

```
if (mkfifo(CONTROLLER_file, 0666) < 0)
    perror("mkfifo");

if((aux_fd = open(CONTROLLER_file, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK) )< 0)
    perror("Opening error");

if((fd = open(CONTROLLER_file, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
    perror("Opening error");
```

I do this to avoid the locking problem waiting for another process to open the file in the other mode.

Writing is done with

```
write(fd, write_buffer, sizeof(write_buffer));
```

On the son, I do

```
if (mkfifo(CONTROLLER_file, 0666) < 0)
    perror("mkfifo");

if((file_descriptor = open(CONTROLLER_file, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    perror("Opening error");
```

And I read with

```
if (mkfifo(CONTROLLER_file, 0666) < 0)
    perror("mkfifo");

if((file_descriptor = open(CONTROLLER_file, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    perror("Opening error");
```

The message is sent successfully.

For testing I kill the main program using kill on the Linux terminal and the children continue to run. I call again the main program and it goes into the part of reestablishing communication with the same procedure presented above, opening the same file. I then try to send a message to the child, but he receives nothing.

Does anyone have any idea how I can reestablish this communication?

Comment: I think the child needs to close and re-open the file on error.

Comment: I might be missing something, but: 1. What's the container (datastructure?) you are using for communication? 2. Can you debug the child's view of the container?

Comment: Just to clarify, the idea of using FIFO was abandoned in the face of project changes, so I did not move the topic any further. With that I also did not find a solution to the problem to share here.